# Query Mongo DB MONTH & Weeks from UNIXSTAMP

Tags: mongodb

I have mongodb collection of documents such as:

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5a0b86e3212cba197b7e9da6"),
    "name" : "Internal",
    "startTimestamp" : 1510704780,
    "endTimestamp" : null,
    "place" : "H",
    "description" : "J",
    "status" : "DONE",
}
```

I want to filter startTimestamp per month and per week

Comment: So for instance, you want all documents for April, whatever the year?

Comment: yes ,,, i want to show current month

Comment: @RhieIdeotechnology "current month" implies current year. You didn't answer Xavier's question. Take a look if you can use anything from https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation-date/